# Using volatility cycles to switch between trend following & range bound trading?

Tags: volatility, quant-trading-strategies, stochastic-volatility

> *"...a low volatility environment is usually a good environment for trend following strategies; see Jez Liberty’s state of trend following report here..."*
>   http://quantumfinancier.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/regime-switching-system-using-volatility-forecast/
>   (By the way the volatility is defined as the "std. deviation of the price rate of change" )

I am not a professional quant with education on related subjects.
Therefore I am not capable of testing the idea above thoroughly.
Would you approve that **trend following strategies(TFS) perform better under lower vol.?**
If yes then what would be a suitable method to exploit this idea?

==> switching to TF strategies when the volatility is below a trigger value (e.g. mov. average)?
==> switching to TF strategies when the volatility is turning down from an extreme reading (e.g. going back under the upper bollinger band)?
==> none?

Comment: -1 As always, this depends on the specific trend following system.  Do your own testing.  There is no substitute.